# Voltage inverter with MC34063A, input voltage drops on connection

Tags: mc34063

I designed a circuit with an [MC34063A](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc34063a-d.pdf) to get -12V output from +5V.

The problem is that when I connect +5V to pin 6 (VCC) of MC34063A , +5V drops to 2V. Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: If your input voltage drops this means that your circuit draws more current than your 5V Voltage Source can deliver.
What kind of Voltage Source are you using? What load is connected to your converter?

Comment: I have input voltage of 24V (SMPS). Converted it to +12V, 3A using TPS54340. +12V used for OP07. Also +12V is converted to +5V, 100mA using (MIC5209). then i try to convert +5V to -12V. I use -12V for OP07.

Comment: Your schematic seems to be right. Except maybe for C16 which might influence regulation performnce. Check and double check your setup. Also please attach an image of your setup.

Comment: i removed C16 and checked. Nothing happens.

Comment: 100 mA from 5 volts may not be enough to overcome initial surge currents. What sort of over-current sensing level does you circuit have?

Comment: For future reference: for switching regulators input go "close to the source". Use either the 24V input or the +12V input. Other than with linear regulators you don't have power that big of a power issue and switching regulators can influence each other with pulse loads.

Comment: can you use another +5V souce (maybe an USB phone charger) to see if your circuit works than?

Comment: I used another 5V input (5V,3A) but i/p voltage drop to 1.8V & MC34063 gives -2.5V. Also as stated in datasheet for line regulation 4.5V to 6V @ 100mA is suitable. so why is this happening. Also i used to cut all loads and tested nothing happens.